# Segmentation Fault in creating a cv::Mat from unsigned char array

Tags: c++, opencv

I cannot understand why the following minimal code outputs segmentation fault and cv::Mat values are not printed correctly:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    unsigned char out[1280*720*3/2] = {100};
    cv::Mat dummy_query = cv::Mat(1, 1280*720*3/2*sizeof(unsigned char), CV_8UC1, (void *)out);
    cv::Size s = dummy_query.size();
    std::cout << s << "\r\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 1280*720*3/2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << "ss" << int(out[i]) << ":";
        std::cout << dummy_query.at<int>(0,i) << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `unsigned char out[1280*720*3/2] = {100};` (more than 1 MB) too much to be allocated on stack. You got stack overflow. Use dynamic array allocated on heap.

Comment: `3/2` is `1`. Are you sure that formula to calculate size is correct?

Comment: Let open CV allocate memory for this (use different constructor without providing buffer).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Isn't the multiplication done left to right?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number first multiplication is done then result of that  is divided, so it will divide by 2 without problems.

Comment: @rafix07 oh, right. I used to know this. Thank you.

Comment: @MarekR thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted to avoid copies. I will allocate memory on heap now.

Comment: `dummy_query.at<int>(0,i)` -- wrong type, data / Mat is uchar

Answer (score -1):

You have defined uchar datatype in `cv::Mat`  but accessing at this line
as int `std::cout << dummy_query.at<int>(0,i) << " ";`

so your program will likely get crash at end of the loop
e.g.

```
// create a 100x100 8-bit matrix
Mat M(100,100,CV_8U);
// this will be compiled fine. no any data conversion will be done.
Mat_<float>& M1 = (Mat_<float>&)M;
// the program is likely to crash at the statement below
M1(99,99) = 1.f;
```

check this open cv [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id7)

Comment: OpenCV 2.4 is dead ("end of life"). it receives no support. nobody should use it. **you** shouldn't link to docs for version 2.4 unless the situation requires it. -- further, your answer merely reiterates the problem posed in the question, without suggesting a solution. since you wrote this answer *after* someone pointed out the issue and gave a solution in the comments, this is *really low hanging fruit*.

Comment: I have referred older doc because it has the explanation but I couldn't find that example on a newer version of the doc. also, the question seems like they want some concept explanation rather than to get updated code that's why I just explain the thing nothing more

Comment: the solution was already answered in the comment box so does that mean my answer should get downvoted? thank you for your valuable suggestion i will improve my self on next time

Comment: v4.x documentation link to the same information: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#details